# When getting the local vol surface from the implied vol surface, do we interpolate the strikes?

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility, volatility-surface, interpolation, volatility-interpolation

Using the dupire method:
$$\sigma(T, K)=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}^2+2 \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}} T\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}}{\partial T}+(r-q) K \frac{\partial \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}}{\partial K}\right)}{1+2 d_1 K \sqrt{T} \frac{\partial \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}}{\partial K}+K^2 T\left(d_1 d_2\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}}{\partial K}\right)^2+\sigma_{\mathrm{imp}} \frac{\partial^2 \sigma_{\mathrm{imp}}}{\partial K^2}\right)}}$$

According to [Clark (2011)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119208679) we're only supposed to interpolate across the time domain because, there is no connection with vol across different strikes. For stock options, do I interpolate the implied vol surface across both strike and time?